# selective print between regexp

Tags: perl, sed

I need to catch a CSV portion of a text file from a REGEXP until the second blank line. Something like below:

```
garbage garbage
garbage garbage
garbage garbage

REGEXP

data,data,data
data,data,data

garbage garbage
garbage garbage
garbage garbage
```

Any ideas how to do this in sed or perl will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ne '$on=1 if /REGEXP/; if ($on) { print; $blank++ if /^\s*$/; last if $blank == 2 }' file.csv
```

Will display:

```
    REGEXP

data,data,data
data,data,data
```

If you don't want to display `REGEXP`:

```
perl -ne '$on=1 and next if /REGEXP/; if ($on) { print; $blank++ if /^\s*$/; last if $blank == 2 }' file.csv
```

Comment: After @tadmc just introduced me to `perl -00` (+1, btw), I realized you could also to something like: `perl -0ne '/REGEXP\n\n(.*\n)\n.*\n\n/s; print $1' file.csv`

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -00 -ne 'print, print(scalar <>), exit if /REGEXP/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    /^REGEXP/ and last;
}

my $csv_line;

while ($csv_line = <DATA>) {
    $csv_line =~ /,/ and last;
}

while (defined($csv_line) and $csv_line =~ /\S/) {
    process_csv($csv_line);
    $csv_line = <DATA>;
}

sub process_csv {
    my ($line) = @_;
    print $line;
}


__DATA__
garbage garbage
garbage garbage
garbage garbage

REGEXP

data,data,data
data,data,data

garbage garbage
garbage garbage
garbage garbage
```

Answer (score 0):

Using record input separator to catch blocks ending with double newlines. This only prints the data section. If you want to print the REGEXP part, uncomment the `say;`

```
$/ = "";
while (<>) {
    next unless /^REGEXP/;
    #say;  # Uncomment to print header
    chomp($_ = <>);
    say;
}
```

Comment: Almost always you want `$/ = ""`, not `$/ = "\n\n"`.